# tibco Spotfire Set filter to last 8 days by default

Tags: date, filter, range, default, spotfire

Can I have a filter that is set to current date - 8days by default. So, whenever a user opens it on the webplayer the filter should show data in the last 8  days and then the user can change the filter around.

Answer (score 4):

you can accomplish this by setting a Data Limiting Expression with an expression like

```
[Date] >= DateAdd("day", -8, DateTimeNow())
```

Comment: Hi Niko, This will limit the data in the chart. In the chart I have, I have data for a month ie 30 days, but whenever a user opens it I wanted it to default filter to 8 days and then user can adjust the filter the dates based on his needs.

Comment: this is important context and should go in the original question. please edit your question to reflect this.